# How to create two WAR out of one project, containing their own web.xml

Tags: rest, maven, web, war, packaging

My project has several maven modules. However, it has two web modules, one for rest service another for web. These both have their own seperate web.xml. I want to create two seperate war files for these two modules, both war with different names. Please guide me how can I do it.

Note: These both modules use other existing maven modlues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing blocks you to have two war modules (`<packaging>war</packaging>` element) as part of a multi-module maven project.
Those two war modules would then provide the `web.xml` file in the default location expected by Maven (actually, the [Maven War Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)): `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` and depending on their dependencies to other modules, they will also add to the war libs other modules jars.

If you are not happy with the default war name and you don't need further configuration for it, you don't even need to configure the [Maven War Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin), simply rename the final artifact via the build `<finalName>warName</finalName>` element (NOTE: don't include the `.war` extension here).

Comment: Thanks Matteo. But how can we give two separate names to these two war files. Is it possible to give the war file names in their respective pom.xml files? Currently that name is in parent pom.xml, because of that I am getting one .war and another war folder with the same name.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Did you try configuring the fileName element in the build section of each concerned pom?